# QueryString parameter to close modal dialog for Discussion Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, discussion-board, community-site

I'm using Modal Dialog to show a  Discussion Thread  from a Discussion List, There is an option to delete the Discussion in OOTB Thread View,The dialog has to be closed when the user deletes the Discussion item, But the page in dialog is redirecting to Site Home page, Is there any parameter like "DlgClose=1" to close the dialog after completing the delete action.
[image]

Comment: CloseOnCancel=1 is a similar parameter